# Quitar un caracter de un string en java

Tags: java

espero me puedan ayudar tengo un arreglo en java y deseo quitarle un caracter que sea diferente a "a" o "b" y actualice la cadena.
Por ejemplo: si viene un aa9b quitarle el 9 y asignarle el valor aab o si viene abab8abaa quitarle el 8 tengo una variable que recorre la cadena una a una pues pueden existir dos caracteres invalidos por ejemplo ab2aba8 y deberia quitar el 2 y posteriormente el 8.
Lo que tengo es algo asi:

if (((cadena.charAt(index)) != 'a') && ((cadena.charAt(index) != 'b'))) {

*//Dentro de este if necesito actualizar a "cadena" en la posición "index".*

}

Ya intente con **cadena = cadena.substring(0,index);** pero me corta la cadena hasta encontrar el primer carácter no valido. Por ejemplo con aaaa@aa me deja el string cadena como aaaa quitándome las dos ultimas letras a.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Otra solucion para que la busqueda sea mas eficiente, es busar el caracter que menos se repite y quitarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quitar un caracter de un string en java

Puedes utilizar el método `replaceAll()`, el cual **reemplaza** cada subcadena de la cadena que coincida con la expresión regular dada por una secuencia de reemplazo, y nos devuelve un `String`

Ejemplo para que puedas entender mejor..

```
String cadena = "ab87ba93abb";
System.out.println("Cadena: " + cadena.replaceAll("[^a-b]", ""));
```

**Resultado:**
`Cadena: abbaabb`

La expresión regular que le he pasado como parámetro, **reemplaza** todo lo que **no sean** `a` o `b` por una **cadena vacía**.